# How to put all the other pages in a base template without using a web framework

Tags: php, python, html, django

By django, one can use a base template for a common navbar and a footer:

Firstly, adding

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

to the base template.

Secondly, adding

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

to the secondary pages.

Is there a method to do this using php but without a web framework?

Comment: You could use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: Ofcourse its possible but you have to write your own engine. Atleast you have to parse and be able to read all those syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You could use a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) (for example, used by Prestashop) or [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) (for example used by Symphony).

If you search a little bit on Google "php template engine" you'll find some more.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's why I answered this... Smarty and Twig aren't FrameWorks, they're template engines.

Comment: @VuralAcar, Prestashop and Twig was mention only for example.